# What effect do the power ups have?

Tags: spell-up

I missed the description of the power ups in the tutorial section, and I can't find a way to repeat the information.

**What do each of the power ups do?**

[image: Sample of some of the power ups]
[image: Sample of some of the power ups]
[image: Sample of some of the power ups]

Note: I'm referring to the [Chrome Experiment](https://spellup.withgoogle.com/), not the Android game with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is what each power-up does:

---

[image: Reveal power-up button]
[image: Reveal power-up description]

[image: Shield power-up button]
[image: Shield power-up description]

[image: Tally power-up button]
[image: Tally power-up description]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is a great start, but there are more than just these three power ups in the game. I added a couple more images in my question to show examples of some of the other ones.

Comment: I have added some others, If you come across any more, just tell me!